# Paying less interest rate in credit card

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

I think I've found a way to pay off my credit cards faster, and therefore paying less interest rate. There's a Google Spreadsheet with my work at http://goo.gl/NqliZM

**My question**

What payment strategy will save me the most money? From my spreadsheet, I believe my idea actually works (saves me money), but is this reasoning actually correct?

**Explanation**

My scenario is this: I have 2 credit cards, both maxed out at \$5000. Credit card A has an interest rate of 10%, and card B has a rate of 20%. I have unlimited and free balance transfers from card B into card A. So my idea is this:

I only have a fixed \$300 to put on these cards every month. I could either pay \$150 on each card, or pay \$300 on card A, then transfer \$300 from card B into card A. I've checked with my bank, and they assured me I can in fact do this if I so choose.

**My conclusion**

Based on the results from my spreadsheet, I'd end up paying about 33% less interest total (\$2,145.71 vs \$3,180.98) if I use the strategy where I pay the entire \$300 on one card, then transfer that amount onto the other card. Can someone with more experience verify that this is in fact correct?

**Edit**

By *transferring from card B to A* I mean doing a **credit card balance transfer**. Meaning bank A cuts me a check, which they take from my credit line, then I pay that check to bank B, which lowers my debt with them.

```
Month 1:
Card A - balance: $5,000
Card B - balance: $5,000

   Pay $300 on card A
Card A - balance: $4,700
Card B - balance: $5,000

   Transfer $300 from card B to A
Card A - balance: $5,000
Card B - balance: $4,700

// --------

Month 2:
Card A - balance: $5,000
Card B - balance: $4,700

   Pay $300 on card A
Card A - balance: $4,700
Card B - balance: $4,700

   Transfer $300 from card B to A
Card A - balance: $5,000
Card B - balance: $4,400
```

Comment: Why not pay $\$300$ on card $B$ inestead of putting it on $A$ and then transfering it? The rule of thumb is "money goes to the highest interest". So you should simply never have a credit on $B$, unless $A$ is maxed out.

Comment: Well, they are both maxed out, and I need to make a minimum payment on both of them each month. Right now the minimum payment on both is something like \$120 on one, and \$110 on the other. I can't just simply put down \$300 on one card, and nothing on the other.

Comment: Well, that's differnt from what you stated above. The rule of thumb still holds: Get rid of credit on $B$ as fast as possible.

Comment: I see. So since I only have $300 to put on my cards each month, if I put the entire $300 on card B by transferring that amount into card A, then technically I'm still paying off card B as fast as I possibly can, no?!

Comment: By the way, when you say "transfer from B to A", do you mean transfer *money*, that is increase your debt on card B and decreas your debt on card A, or transfer *debt*, that is decrease your debt on B and increase your debt on A? If the first is the case, your bank would only allow you to worsen your situation, how kind of them

Comment: By transferring from B to A I mean doing a credit card balance transfer. Meaning bank A cuts me a check, which they take from my credit line, then I pay that check to bank B, which lowers my debt with them. So if I pay \$300 on card A, then transfer \$300 from card B, at the end of the day card A will have the same balance, but card B will have decreased by that \$300.

Comment: Ah, in that case, essentially paying 300 to A and transferring 300 from A to B is the same as paying 300 to B, hence the prefered strategy according to the interest rates.

Answer (score 0):

just to finish the question

- it is best to pay off credit card B ( because this one has the highest interest rate) as soon as possible.
- I think if you just pay 300,-- to card B you can get problems with card A, so probably you need to pay something to card A.
- if card A allows you to make new debt max it out , but only use it to reduce the debt on card B.

Mathematicly just paying off card B is best , but there can be some juridical problems with that solution, but try to get as close as possible.

Comment: Two things I've concluded from posting this: 1) neither Willemien nor @hagen-von-eitzen know anything about how balance transfers work with credit cards, and 2) neither one of you know how to read a question thoroughly... You don't seem to be very practical people.

Comment: you are correct in my case , i don't use credit cards